# Angular (4) migration errors

Tags: angular, typescript, migration

Just migrated to Angular(4) by using the [Migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update) from the github repository of Angular.

The first error I get is `ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule`.
The second and third one are the exact same, I changed my `main.ts` and `polyfills.ts` to respectively:

`main.ts`

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

`polyfills.ts`

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

They give this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
at Object.getNewLineCharacter (C:\development\projects-git\mydoc\static-
web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:9580:20)
at Object.createCompilerHost (C:\development\projects-git\mydoc\static-
web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:66674:26)
at Object.ngcLoader (C:\development\projects-git\mydoc\static-
web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:202:31)
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
```

npm: '4.5.0'
node: '6.10.1'
typescript: 2.3.2

Comment: Migrated from what exactly? Your provided link only applies to cli generated projects from earlier versions of the cli, and then as noted a recent cli project needs no "migration" at all. Possibly confusing terms here? Is this mayble actually an AngularJS project you are trying to "migrate" to Angular?

Comment: It was an Angular 2.4.6 project to Angular 4.1

Comment: An "existing cli" project? Point is that the "guide" you are reading is all about the "cli" version rather than the "Angular version". So as stated on the page, *"beta.28 or less"* means "pre webpack", which is the only "upgrade" that would really matter. Just bumping the angular versions does not cause the errors you list.

Comment: So it might be some other dependency, if I downgrade the cli it might be a fix?

Comment: I really have no clue how to fix these errors. I removed my node_modules and did npm install and I saw this `-- typescript@2.3.2  invalid` , which I have then again no clue what to do about it.